# I am getting this exeption when i try to start my spring project...Any ideas

Tags: java

HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Driver com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spring_book_shop?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&serverTimezone=UTC"

Comment: As a colleague pointed out, perhaps the driver is not properly written? Instead of "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" it should be "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"?

Comment: @kekec `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` is correct, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-api-changes.html

Comment: Does it work when you remove the properties from the jdbc URL (everything after the `?` including the `?` character)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I had a similar issue. First thing to do is to check any errors in the database or your query. If that isn't the issue, then check your url, my url ended up being wrong. Also, check to see if you need the timezone param.